# why cant I refer Function.identity as method reference in collector

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors, method-reference

Can someone suggest, why am I not able to apply method reference here?

Working Code.

```
System.out.println(
                Arrays.stream(str.split(" "))
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),Collectors.counting())));
```

Compilation Error, Can not resolve method

```
System.out.println(
            Arrays.stream(str.split(" "))
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function::identity,Collectors::counting)));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `groupingBy()` expects a `Function`, i.e. something which takes a single argument, and returns something.

`Function.identity()` **returns** a Function.

But `Function::identity` **references** the `identity()` method, which doesn't take any argument, an can thus not be used as a Function.

Similarly, `groupingBy()` expects, as its second argument, an instance of  `Collector`. `Collectors.counting()` returns a Collector. So you can use that. But `Collector::counting` references the `counting()` method, and a single method taking no argument is not sufficient at all to provide an implementation of the Collector interface, which has 5 methods.

To make a car analogy, if you call a method expecting a vehicle, you can call `garage.getCar()` to get a Car and pass the returned Car as argument. But passing `garage::getCar`would make no sense, because that would be "something that is able to give you a car". And that doesn't qualify as a Vehicle.

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thanks... Grouping By requires a Function as an argument, Whereas if I pass method reference, Method return type will be the argument ,which is not a function.... Thanks.

Comment: Nicely explained.+1